# What is $\det(2\mathrm{adj}(\mathrm{adj}(A)))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What will be the power of $2$ after its taken out from the determinant bracket? And what property will be used?
I am confused with scalar associated with determinant of adjoint property.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: As $A(\textrm{adj} A)=(\det A) I$, we have $\det A\det(\textrm{adj} A)=\det[A(\textrm{adj} A)]=(\det A)^n $, where $n$ is the order of $A$.

$$\det(\textrm{adj}A)=(\det A)^{n-1}$$

Comment: I am concerned with the scalar. What will be the solution of the question i posted?

Comment: @SairajGhate Apply the formula $\det({\rm adj}\,A)=(\det A)^{n-1}$ to the expression $\det(2{\rm adj}({\rm adj}(A)))$. (Also, do you know what $\det(\lambda A)$ is in terms of $\det A$ and $\lambda$? If not, look at a formula for the determinant.)

Comment: @SairajGhate We have $\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n \det A$. I used this formula once in my Hint.

Comment: @SairajGhate Use $\det (\lambda A)=\lambda^n\det A$ first. Then apply the formula in my hint twice.